# не стирает данные из файла после записи

Tags: python, файлы

Ребята помогите, пожалуйста! Этот код берёт число из файла прибавляет 1 и записывает обратно в файл, но он не стирает полностью файл

Вот код

```
with open("save.txt", "r+") as _read:
    #while True:
        file_read = _read.read()
        click = input("click")
        hah = int(file_read) + int(1)
        _read.write("")
        _read.write(str(hah))
```

Comment: Скопируй код с редактора вместе с табами, ибо в питоне блоки кода выделяються именно так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй считать файл, потом его закрыть, потом снова открыть в режиме записи и вывести туда число

```
with open("file.txt", "r+") as _read:
    file_read = _read.read()
 #   click = input("click")
    hah = int(file_read) + int(1)
with open("file.txt","w") as _writefile:
    _writefile.write("")
    _writefile.write(str(hah))
```

Comment: `int(1)` то же самое, что `1`. `_writefile.write("")` не делает ничего.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("save.txt") as inf:
    lst = [int(line) + 1 for line in inf]

with open("save.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.writelines([str(i) + "\n" for i in lst])
```

Этот код работает и для файла с многими строками, по одному целому числу в каждой строке.

В первой части он читает строки файла и создает список из чисел в них, увеличивая каждое число на 1.

В другой части записывает числа из этого списка обратно в файл, конвертируя их на строки и добавляя к каждому из них знак перехода на новую строку (`\n`).

Answer (score 0):

Можно и в режиме `r+` эту задачу решить, просто надо "перемотать" позицию на начало файла перед записью:

```
with open("tempFile.txt", "r+") as _read:
    file_read = _read.read()
    click = input("click")
    hah = int(file_read) + 1
    _read.seek(0) # "перемотка" в начало файла
    _read.write(str(hah))
```

Немного лишних конструкций я удалил из кода.

Довольно странно, что никто из отвечавших не помнит про метод `seek`.